# I copied the exact same code from AWS Glue Visual editor and created new ETL script. Getting Connection Timed out error for snowflake

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl, aws-glue

I have a AWS glue ETL that load data from PostgreSQl to Snowflake. I copied the exact same code from AWS Glue Visual editor and created new ETL script. I also set the same VPC and Subnet in Script Job details as well. The AWS Glue ETL is working fine in Visual editor but when I get the script and create new script ETL its giving me the error in snowflake side.

I am using snowflake connection type and I have username and password in AWS Secret Manager for Snowflake.

HTTP request: Connect to qha38537-etlworks-us-prod.snowflakecomputing.com:443 [qha38537-etlworks-us-prod.snowflakecomputing.com/52.27.88.193, qha38537-etlworks-us-prod.snowflakecomputing.com/44.241.78.214, qha38537-etlworks-us-prod.snowflakecomputing.com/34.215.202.59] failed: connect timed out.

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

# Script generated for node PostgreSQL
PostgreSQL_node1699996107716 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="postgresql",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "dc.action",
        "connectionName": "DCvNEXT_POSTGRES",
    },
    transformation_ctx="PostgreSQL_node1699996107716",
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: The error message is related to a timeout when attempting to connect to your Snowflake instance: Check (Network Configuration, Security Groups and NACLs, AWS Glue Connection, Snowflake Availability) **nb** so it's not proof that the ETL is in error

Comment: What about trying the script from this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Use-AWS-Glue-With-Snowflake)?